# How to display the content of an array inside an object in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a React component. When the user makes a form selection, it retrieves the following object (the content of the object varies depending on the selection made):

**Data**

```
jsonObj={
 "name":"main",
 "type":"meat",
 "values":[
      ["chicken","Roast chicken with vegetables"],
      ["beef","Beef and Yorkshire pudding"]
]}
```

**Desired results**

Here's what I want to display on screen when rendered:

```
<div>
    <label htmlFor="chicken">Roast chicken and vegetables</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label htmlFor="beef">Beef and Yorkshire pudding</label>
</div>
```

**My failed attempt!**

```
Object.entries(jsonObj["values"]).map(([val,index]))=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <label htmlFor={val[index][0]}>{jsonSub[key][1]}:</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The result of this is:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

And when I try it in the browser console I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list". Is anyone able to help me get my desired results?!

Many thanks!

Katie

Comment: I don't think `map` takes an array, shouldn't that `[val,index]` just be `val,index`? (And it looks like you may be closing your arrow function before it's started with an extra close bracket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.entries` method is meant to get array from object, But your "values" is already array, So directly use the `map`

```
jsonObj["values"].map(([html, text]) => (
  <div>
    <label htmlFor={html}>{text}</label>
  </div>
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `Object.entries()`. Simply using `.map()` on `jsonObj.values` and accessing on each iteration the current array of elements and showing up `e[0]` and `e[1]` for `<label>`.

Instead you can do it easier like the following:

```
jsonObj.values.map(e => {
   return <div>
       <label htmlFor={e[0]}>{e[1]}</label>
   </div>
});
```

See the following example:

```js
const jsonObj = {
 "name":"main",
 "type":"meat",
 "values":[
      ["chicken","Roast chicken with vegetables"],
      ["beef","Beef and Yorkshire pudding"]
]}

const result = jsonObj.values.map(e => {
   // just returning a template literal for representation
   return `<label htmlFor="${e[0]}">${e[1]}</label>`;
});

console.log(result)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you norbitrial for a great answer and the code snippet too! Really appreciate your speedy response :-D